# How to use href inside rich:column?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, href

I'm new to xhtml and I am trying to use href inside a table's cell via a certain name(auction's name in my case). When I press the auction's name, I want to be send inside another page for adding a bid, seeing hightest bid and so on. It just shows me the last panel Group from the referenced page(where it says: No bids for this auction).

Can someone help me please ?

the code from rich:column is auctionList.xhtml:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <rich:dataTable id="auctionsTable" rows="6" value="#{cc.attrs.auctions}" var="auct" border="1" styleClass="flat list auctions" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and not empty cc.attrs.auctions}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <rich:dataScroller forComponent="auctionsTable" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:link outcome="/destination" value="link" />


        <rich:column sortBy="#{auct.name}" sortOrder="ascending" >
            <a href="detail.xhtml">
            #{auct.name}
            </a>                
        </rich:column>
```

and detail.xhml is:

```
<ui:composition>

    <h2>Details</h2>
    <h:panelGroup layout="div"
        rendered="#{auctionManager.currentAuction != null}">
        <a4j:poll interval="3000" render="highestBidOutput, bidHistory" action="#{auctionManager.refreshAuction(currentAuction)}" />
        <h3>#{currentAuction.name}</h3>
        <h:panelGrid>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="ID:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{currentAuction.id}" />
            </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="Owner:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{currentAuction.owner.name}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="Original price:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{currentAuction.originalPrice}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="Description:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{currentAuction.description}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="Location:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{currentAuction.location}" />
        </h:column>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Highest bid:"
                rendered="#{not empty currentAuction.highestBid}" />
            <h:outputText id="highestBidOutput"
                value="#{currentAuction.highestBid.amount} (#{currentAuction.highestBid.bidder.name})"
                rendered="#{not empty currentAuction.highestBid}" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Bid" rendered="#{loginManager.logged}" />
            <h:form rendered="#{loginManager.logged}">
                <h:inputText id="bidAmountInput" value="#{bidAmount}"
                    validator="#{bidValidator.validateBid}" />
                <h:commandButton value="Add"
                    action="#{auctionManager.addBid(bidAmount)}" />
                <h:messages style="color: red" />
            </h:form>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGroup id="bidHistory" rendered="#{not empty currentAuction.bids}">
            <h3>Bids</h3>
            <h:dataTable var="offer" value="#{currentAuction.bids}" border="1"
                styleClass="flat">
                <h:column>#{offer.bidder.name}</h:column>
                <h:column>#{offer.amount}</h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup layout="div"
        rendered="#{auctionManager.currentAuction == null}">
        <p>No bids for given auction.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

and AuctionManagerImpl.java used in detail.xhtml:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Auction currentAuction = null;

@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;

@Inject
private LoginManager loginManagerBean;

@Resource SessionContext sessionContext;

@Produces
@Named
@Dependent
@CurrentAuction
@PermitAll
public Auction getCurrentAuction() {
    if (currentAuction != null && !em.contains(currentAuction)) {
        currentAuction = em.merge(currentAuction);
    }
    return currentAuction;
}

@PermitAll
public Long getCurrentAuctionId() {
    return (currentAuction == null) ? null : currentAuction.getId();
}

@PermitAll
public void setCurrentAuctionId(Long currentId) {
    this.currentAuction = em.find(Auction.class, currentId);
}

@PermitAll
public List<Auction> getAll() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Auction a", Auction.class)
            .getResultList();
}

@PermitAll
public List<Auction> getAuctionsWinningByUser(User user) {
    String jql = "SELECT auction FROM Auction auction, User user "
            + "WHERE user=:user AND auction.highestBid member of user.bids "
            + "ORDER BY auction.id";
    TypedQuery<Auction> query = em.createQuery(jql, Auction.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    List<Auction> auctions = query.getResultList();
    return auctions;
}

@PermitAll
public List<Auction> getAuctionLoosingByUser(User user) {
    String jql = "SELECT DISTINCT auction FROM User user "
            + "JOIN user.bids bid JOIN bid.auction auction "
            + "WHERE user=:user AND auction.highestBid.bidder != user "
            + "ORDER BY auction.id";
    TypedQuery<Auction> query = em.createQuery(jql, Auction.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    List<Auction> auctions = query.getResultList();
    return auctions;
}

@PermitAll
public void refreshAuction(Auction auction) {
    em.refresh(auction);
}

//@PermitAll
public void addBid(long bidAmount) {
    if (sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "user must be logged in order to add bid");
    }
    if (currentAuction == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "currentAuction have to be selected in order to add bid");
    }

    Bid bid = new Bid(loginManagerBean.getCurrentUser(), currentAuction, bidAmount);
    em.persist(bid);
    em.flush();
    em.refresh(bid);
}
```

}

also very important is list.xhtml where I make use of auctionList.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="templates/home.xhtml">
<ui:param name="activeTab" value="list" />

<ui:define name="content">
    <h2>Auction List</h2>
    <a:auctionList auctions="#{auctionManager.all}" />
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly you need put a value in the request and redirect to destination page, using JSF, a method that have a String, implicitly return a navigation, you can make this in this way:

```
public String sendToPageAndPutValue(){
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put(paramName, paramValue);
   return "pageDestination.xhtml";
}
```

To recover this value in destination Bean you can make this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("paramName")
```

check in your bean.:

```
@Named -> javax.inject.Named
@ViewScoped -> org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped
public class YourBean
```

In the your xhtml, you need call this method in a h:commandButton or a4j:commandButton using the property action

```
<h:commanButton id="idButton" value="Send" execute="@this" action="#{yourBean.sendToPageAndPutValue()}"/>
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. The sendToPageAndPutValue() method i'll call in auctionList.xhtml.. the paramName, paramValue should be auction's name ?.. I cannot see how to make the connection between auction's name and the command button(I would not like to use a <h:selectOneMenu>, can you tell me another solution, please ?).. and for the destination page I'll make another class("DestinationBean").. my question is: to obtain the destination bean's GET value it's OK to make the call in detail.xhtml(my destination page) ? I though of something like: <p>Param: #{destinationbean.paramName}</p>

Comment: The commandButton will call the method sendToPageAndPutValue(), within the method, you must give a name for a auctions to send this to other bean, the paramName is used for recover the value, just it, in this way you can send any object to any place in the other beans.

This will return the object that will put in the request using the paramName: currentAuction = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("paramName");

Comment: Ok. So it's not better to implement the method:  sendToPageAndPutValue() in Auction class(and put param value auction's name declared as atribute), rather than creating a class Your Bean ? I have a class called Auction.java, and also an AuctionManagerImpl.java ?

Comment: Yes, the YourBean is just a example